# how to add different control in gridview row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `gridview` which I populate from the list data. every row in the `gridview` has a text box. there is one row within the `gridview` which I want a `dropdown` control rather then the `textbox`. I can't figure out how to change the textbox to dropdown control from a row in the grid.

My gridview below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  style="width:100%;" ShowHeader="false"
                     CellPadding="3" BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" Font-Bold="false" GridLines="None"
                                    RowStyle-CssClass="GridRow">
    <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Label ID="lbl_ItemID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GroupItemTypeID") %>' ></asp:Label>
               </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Label ID="lbl_ItemCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GroupItemTypeCode") %>' ></asp:Label>
               </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="310px" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_ItemValuesName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ControlName") %>'  ></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="245px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrice" runat="server"  CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="RowWid">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_IsPercentbased" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PercentBasedText") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="70px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkIsPercent" runat="server"  />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind

```
private void GetItemValues()
{
    List<Entities.ItemValues> IValues = new List<Entities.ItemValues>();

    IValues = BLL.PriceGroupItemValues.GetAllPriceGroupItemValues();

    GridView1.DataSource = IValues;

    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: So you want drop-down in some of the rows and textbox in other rows ?

Comment: Add `dropdown` control below the `textbox` in `aspx` source. Make both `textbox` and `dropdown` as `false` for `visible` property. Then, in `code-behind`, whichever `row` you need to show the `textbox`, set textbox's `visible` property to `true`. Similarly make the `visible` property `true` for `dropdown` control wherever you need.

Comment: John, here i know which row i want a dropdown. i want it on the last row within the grid. setting visibility to control then how do i populate the grid from the code behind?

Comment: At present, can you able to *populate* the `grid` with `textbox` for the last row ?

Comment: no., but if i put a dropdown then i will require to populate it.

Comment: I am not getting your problem clearly. Can you explain the problem that you are facing with little clarity ?

Comment: i have a grid with textbox in every row. textbox's within the grid is empty. i want to add dropdown in the last row of the gridview whose label text Eval("GroupItemTypeCode") is "SUBFREQ". if i change a text box to a dropdown, then i would need textvalue and textname to be specified. i have a textvalue and textname stored in a xml format in one db table

 <LIST><row><value>MON</value><disp>Monthly</disp></row><row><value>QLY</value><disp>quartely</disp></row></LIST>

i want to populate this in the dropdown which ill be creating within the gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some work around with the solution Harvey provided and my existing code. Posting my answer here.

In the gridview, created 2 control and visibility of one control(dropdown) to false

```
 <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="245px">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrice" runat="server"  CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:DropDownList ID="ddFrequencyBilling" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Visible="false"></asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

In the RowDataBound event of the gridview

```
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                //foreach( GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                //{
                    String ItemCode = (e.Row.FindControl("lbl_ItemCode") as Label).Text;

                    if ( ItemCode == "SUBFREQ")
                    {
                        List<Entities.ItemValues> PGItemValues = new List<Entities.ItemValues>();

                        TextBox TextBoxtemp = ((TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtPrice"));

                        TextBoxtemp.Visible = false;

                        Label lbel = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbl_IsPercentbased"));

                        lbel.Visible = false;

                        CheckBox chk = ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("ChkIsPercent"));

                        chk.Visible = false;

                        DropDownList dd1 = ((DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddFrequencyBilling"));

                        dd1.Visible = true;

                        PGItemValues = BLL.PriceGroupItemValues.GetItemValueOnCode(ItemCode, 1);

                        dd1.DataSource = PGItemValues;

                        dd1.DataTextField = "IValue";

                        dd1.DataValueField = "ItemCode";

                        dd1.DataBind();
                    }
                //}
            }
```

and yes it worked. Thanks alot guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for this approach in your case :

Put a `TextBox` and `DropDown` both in that `TemplateField` where your TextBox is currently, and set `Visible=false` in your Dropdown.

Now in your code-behind, you can use the `GridView.RowDataBound` event to alternatively display the `TextBox` or the `Dropdown` whenever and wherever you require. Something like this :

```
public void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      // set Dropdown visible = true/false as per your requirement.
    }
    else
    {
      // set Textboxvisible = true/false as per your requirement.
    }
  }
```

This event will fire up for ear row in your `GridView` and based on the condition that is specified, you can manipulate which control you want to show in that particular row. You can find the dropdown control like this :

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    categoryName = ((DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlCategoryName"));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi, i tired this but i couldn't find dropdown control which is set visible = false. the control is in the grid

Comment: <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="245px">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrice" runat="server"  CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddFrequencyBilling" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Visible="false"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                String ItemCode = (e.Row.FindControl("lbl_ItemCode") as Label).Text;

                if ( ItemCode == "SUBFREQ")
                {
                   
                }
            }
        }

Comment: See my updated answer. That is how you can find a dropdown using `FindControl` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use a placeholder control instead of a textbox and programmatically add either a textbox or DDL to the Placeholder control in the rowdatabound event based on your criteria

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
                  DataKeyNames="user_id">
      <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="user_id" HeaderText="user_id" ReadOnly="True" InsertVisible="False"
                    SortExpression="user_id"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="user_logon" HeaderText="user_logon" SortExpression="user_logon">
                </asp:BoundField>

        <asp:TemplateField>
          <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Sample DataSources

```
'Primary Datasource to bind to the gridview
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:SomeConnectionString %>'
    SelectCommand="select top 10 user_id, user_logon from your_user_table"></asp:SqlDataSource>

'Secondary datasource to bind to the ddl
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:SomeConnectionString %>'
    SelectCommand="select top 5 user_id, user_logon from your_user_table"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code behind, based on the whether the user_id is odd or even I place one or the other control:

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim ph As PlaceHolder = e.Row.FindControl("PlaceHolder1")

        If GridView1.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Value Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Dim tb As New TextBox()
            tb.Enabled = False
            tb.Text = CType(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)("user_logon")
            ph.Controls.Add(tb)
        Else
            Dim ddl As New DropDownList()
            ddl.DataSourceID = SqlDataSource2.ID
            ddl.DataTextField = "user_logon"
            ddl.DataValueField = "user_id"
            ph.Controls.Add(ddl)
            ddl.DataBind()
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

EDIT based on your Comments:

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim ph As PlaceHolder = e.Row.FindControl("PlaceHolder1")

        If CType(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)("GroupItemTypeID") ="SUBFREQ" Then
            Dim ddl As New DropDownList()
            ddl.DataSourceID = <substitute your requirements>
            ddl.DataTextField = ...
            ddl.DataValueField = ...
            ph.Controls.Add(ddl)
            ddl.DataBind()
        Else
            Dim tb As New TextBox()
            tb.Enabled = ...whatever...
            tb.Text = CType(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)("GroupItemTypeID")
            ph.Controls.Add(tb)
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but did a work around with my earlier code.